# D3 Redraw Y-axes dynamically

Tags: d3.js

I would like to create a dynamic graph with multiple (linear) axes. After the axes have been drawn, I would like (as new data arrives) to change the Data Domain and redraw/update the axes. Can I select the existing axis with D3 and do this or do I have to explicitly save each axis in my code? I hope my question is not confusing.

```
// init all Y-Axis
$.each(chart.YAxes, function (index) {
            var yScale, yAxis;
            yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([chartHeight, 0]);
            yScale.domain([this.YMin, this.YMax]);

            yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                        .scale(yScale)
                        .ticks(10, this.Title)
                        .orient("left");

            d3Chart.append("g")
                   .attr("class", "yAxis " + "y" + this.ID)
                   .call(yAxis);
......

// update Y-Axis (after new data arrives...)
var myYAxis = d3.select(".y" + yAxis.ID);
var myScale = myYAxis. **// get Scale ??**
myScale.domain([newYMin, newYMax]);   
d3Chart.select(".y" + yAxis.ID)
            .transition().duration(300).ease("sin-in-out")
            .call(myYAxis);
```

thx...!

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep references to the axis object so that you can call it again. Selecting the DOM element that contains it and calling that won't work. There are lots of examples on how to update axes, e.g. in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16919280/how-to-update-axis-using-d3-js).

Comment: I agree with you, at least, I was unable to get it working. Honestly, I think there should be a way to do that. In fact, in the example that you have put the only global reference in the three parts of the code is just the svg object, which I think we can get from the DOM. But then, it is true it is not redrawing the scale and I don't understand why....

Comment: @ackuser You should probably post a separate question about this. At least from your comment it's not clear to me what the problem is.