# redrawing axis in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

I am implementing parallel coordinates chart dragging using d3.js

I draw my x-axis with the following code

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().orient("bottom").scale(xScale);
svg.append("g").attr("class", "axis").attr("transform", "translate(" + 0      + " ," + Y_SCALE + ")").call(xAxis);
```

When I drag one of the x-axis, I can re-draw x-axis using the same code in the `"on("dragend"...)` event, but I don't know how to hide the previous one.

Can you please let me know how to hide the previous x-axis or do something more intelligent?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [D3 Redraw Y-axes dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21879025/d3-redraw-y-axes-dynamically)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update axis using d3.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16919280/how-to-update-axis-using-d3-js)