# Simple transition between datasets on click

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to allow the user to switch between the visualisation of two different datasets on click. I am not an expert neither in CSS or JavaScript. I tried to replicate [this example](https://gist.github.com/enjalot/1429426).

The visualisation works in the sense that the bars are visualised when the page loads. Yet it's totally static, when I click the buttons (which in my mind should call the function `bars()` depressingly nothing happens.

I guess I don't understand the mechanics of the click event... But also why the function `exit()` is never called on my `bars`?

Here the complete html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <title>Bar Transition Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body>

<div id="buttons">
        <button id="data1">Dataset 1</button>
        <button id="data2">Dataset 2</button>
        </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 60},
    width = 300 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(5);

data1 = [{"label":"apples","value":6000},{"label":"pears","value":5000},{"label":"bananas","value":4000}]

data2 = [{"label":"apples","value":4000},{"label":"pears","value":6000},{"label":"bananas","value":7000}]


function bars(data)
{

    x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.label; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

   bars = d3.select("svg").selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)

    //enter
    bars.enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.label); })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });

    //exit
    bars.exit()
    .transition()
    .duration(300)
    .remove()

}


function init()
{

    //setup the svg
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    //setup our ui
    d3.select("#data1")
        .on("click", function(d,i) {
            bars(data1)
        })   
    d3.select("#data2")
        .on("click", function(d,i) {
            bars(data2)
        })   

    bars(data1)
}

init();
    </script>

 </body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Clicking the button actually produces a JavaScript error

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
```

which I don't understand since exactly the same line `bars(data1)` is correctly executed when the page is first loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues in your code. The first is that you're overwriting your `bars` function with a d3 selection which is an object and it's causing errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
```

To solve it, just rename your `bars` function to something like `render` (or whatever) and keep the selection as `bars`.

The second issue is that you don't have any code that defines how to update the elements when new data comes in. You have defined only `enter` and `exit` behavior, so the elements are never updated in place. To define it, just reuse parts of your `enter` selection behavior:

```
// Update selection:
bars.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.label); })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });
```

Finally, the reason the `exit` function is never called is because the elements are indexed by a numeric index by default (in your case: 0, 1, 2). When you reset the data, the indexes are the same, so d3 thinks it should **update** elements in place.

Here's a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5pco2zut/).

Comment: That's work! Probably this is a different question, but how should I `exit()` the scales? `var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");` & within the `render()` function     `svg.append('g')
 .attr("class", "x axis")
 .attr('transform', 'translate(' + [margin.left, height +  margin.top] + ')')
 .call(xAxis);`

Comment: You shouldn't do plain `svg.append('g')` in the render function if you plan to call it multiple times because you'll end up with multiple overlapping axis groups. Rather do a single `append` in the init function, then, within `render` function, update scale domain and `.call(xAxis)` whenever new data comes in.

Comment: I also found a related answer for axes update: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16923043/1707938