# Scaling the axis on window re-size with d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to redraw the bar chart if the window is re-sized which is working fine but I also need to redraw the axis which for some reason is just not working, here is my code

```
          $(window).resize(function change() {

                 var tempScale;
                 var newAxis;
                 //bar chart is drawn horizontally
                 if ($(window).width() < width) {

                     //create a new scale on window resize
                     tempScale = d3.scale.linear()                         
                     .domain([0, d3.max(arr)])
                     .range([0, $(window).width()]);

                     // intialize newAxis which is adjusted to tempScale
                     newAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(tempScale);

                 }

                 else {
                     //set tempScale to default scale 
                     tempScale = scale1;
                 }

                 //modify the bar chart according to new scale
                 canvas2.selectAll("rect")
                 .data(arr)
                 .attr("width", function (d) { return tempScale(d); })
                 .attr("height", 10)
                 //this call is not working
                 .call(newAxis);

             });
```

Also I get can error "Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined". Hope I provided enough information thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not initialising `newAxis` in the `else` branch of your condition.

Comment: Thanks @LarsKotthoff I don't get the error any more. But now a face a weird problem the new axis gets drawn on top of old one and it gets really ugly how can the properly replace old axis with the new one?

Comment: There must be dozens of examples for doing this, see e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16919280/how-to-update-axis-using-d3-js) or [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/3098488).