# Dynamically Update bar chart on dropdown selection change D3 javascript

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to update bar chart on dropdown selection changed. When I change the selection the new bar chart gets appended on the bottom of the already existing chart. How can I get it to update the existing bar chart or remove the existing one and add the new one. I am new to D3 javascript and need some help. I have looked at other similar question on stack overflow and other resources but they somehow don't work. Please look at code:

```
<script>
    var data =  {{ value|safe }}
    function MyGraph(obj) {
        var selectVal = String(obj[obj.selectedIndex].value);
        var width = 1160, height = 400;
        var margin = {top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50};

        //x and y Scales
        var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
                .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

        var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                .range([height, 0]);

        xScale.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.provider_name; }));
        yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
            if(selectVal =="average_coverage"){
            return d.average_coverage;
            }
            else if(selectVal=="average_total_charges"){
                return d.average_total_charges;
            }
            else{
                return d.average_medicare_payments;
            }
        })]);

        //x and y Axes
        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(xScale)
                .orient("bottom");

        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(yScale)
                .orient("left")
                .ticks(25, "$");

        //create svg container
        var svg = d3.select("#graph")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


        xScale.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.provider_name; }));
        yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
             if(selectVal =="average_coverage"){
        return d.average_coverage;
        }
            else if(selectVal=="average_total_charges"){
            return d.average_total_charges;
        }
            else{
            return d.average_medicare_payments;
        }
        })]);


        //create bars
        var bars = svg.selectAll("bar")
                .data(data);
        bars.enter()
                .append("rect")
                //.attr("y",innerHeight)
                .attr("height",0)
                .attr("class", "bar");
        bars.exit().remove();
        bars.transition()
                .duration(700)
                .ease("linear")
                .attr("x",function(d) { return xScale(d.provider_name); })
                .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
                .attr("y", function(d) {
                     if(selectVal =="average_coverage"){
                return yScale(d.average_coverage);
                 }
                    else if(selectVal=="average_total_charges"){
            return yScale(d.average_total_charges);
                     }
                    else{
            return yScale(d.average_medicare_payments);
        }
    })
                .attr("height", function(d) {
                    if(selectVal =="average_coverage"){
                    return height - yScale(d.average_coverage);
                    }
                    else if(selectVal=="average_total_charges"){
                    return height - yScale(d.average_total_charges);
                    }else{
                     return height-yScale(d.average_medicare_payments);
                     }
                })
       svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
        svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);

     //drawing the x axis on svg
    svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

    //drawing the y axis on svg
    svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis)
            .append("text")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("y", 6)
            .attr("dy", ".71em")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .text("Average Cost");
};
```

Comment: All the stuff where you setup the SVG and do the initial append of the SVG to the DOM should only happen once. When you update the chart, you want to update the stuff inside the SVG, but you don't need to append the SVG again.

Comment: Hi @MatthewHerbst thank you for pointing out the mistake out! It now does not append to the existing bar chart. But there one more issue once I made changes as you pointed out. It now makes the new one on top of the existing one. Anyway to fix that issue?

Comment: Hi @MatthewHerbst the above mentioned issue in the comment of overlapping is only for the x and y axis and not for the bar chart. I know I am appending them to the SVG at the end of function and it could be the reason why they are append on top of old axis. Is there be a way where we can dynamically update the axis? Thank you!

Comment: Ideally you should have two functions: one for initial setup and one for updates. In the update function, instead of calculating and appending the updated axis, what you should do is first select the existing axis and update it from there. [This SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16919280/how-to-update-axis-using-d3-js) has a good example of how break up your functions and update your chart components.