# D3 changing X Axis on zoom

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart, axis

I’m trying to add a zoom feature to my bar chart. What I’m trying to achieve is when a user drags his cursor over a certain area, you should be able to zoom in to that area and the x axis value change to showing the number of days in that month. Following this example http://bl.ocks.org/godds/ec089a2cf3e06a2cd5fc. I’ve tried to incorporate the same zoom and drag feature.

I seem to be having issue with changing my x axis values as I’m looking for a way to have the x axis change dynamically when a specific area is selected. Currently when you zoom in the bars all change position but my x axis values remain the same (still show the number of months whereas i want to show the number of days).

My X axis code:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient('bottom')
    .ticks(d3.time.month)
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%b %y'))
    .tickSize(0)
    .tickPadding(8);
```

My brush tool:

```
 function bListener(){
         x.domain(brush.empty() ? x.domain() : brush.extent());
            svg.select(".x axis").call(xAxis);

          svg.selectAll(".bar").attr("transform", function(d) { 
        console.log(d.date); 
        return "translate(" + x(new Date(d.date)) + ",0)"; 

        });
}
```

Complete code can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/noobiecode/wck4ur9d/32/

Any help would be appreciated as I feel my heads going to explode any minute.

Comment: Your zoom into the bar chart doesnt seem to be working properly. But to update the axis just do .call(xAxis) on the container element and that will update

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update axis using d3.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16919280/how-to-update-axis-using-d3-js)

Comment: @thatOneGuy, i'm updating within the bListener function,   svg.selectAll(".x axis").call(xAxis);

Comment: Your zoom function doesnt work too well. It works sometimes but not all the time ....

Comment: where is the code for zooming I dont see any code to zoom in fiddle

Comment: @SiddP, the zooming behavior is done within the blistener function. To get it to work you have to click on any spacing within the bar chart. Currently it's poorly done as i'm still trying to understand it.

Comment: @thatOneGuy, Agreed. I'm still trying to understand it so i will admit it's done very poorly. Any help on that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
svg.select(".x axis").call(xAxis);
```

with

```
 svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
```

moreover better to have a axis and domain for brush separate all together

```
var x2 = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);

var brush = d3.svg.brush()
           .x(x2)
           .on('brush', bListener);
x2.domain(x.domain());
```

**in your bListener function**

```
x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
```

Updated **fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/wck4ur9d/33/

**Note:** Brush and moving axis is not same as zoom.

Comment: Thank you for this. I just have one last question (sorry). Currently I want to display simply the month and the year in the x axis but when zoomed in I wish to display the day of the month. So what I’ve done is simply created a xAxis2 and just changed the     .tickFormat(d3.time.format(' % d %b ')). The issue with this is that the values are too clustered together. Is there an easier to change the values on the x axis. My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/noobiecode/wck4ur9d/42/

Comment: if you are unsure dont have `tickformat` just mention `ticks` for eg: `.ticks(6)` and have full date something like `d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y %H:%M %p")` and everything will be auto adjusted.